# Unit Testing a custom Web API AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit

I am trying to unit test, with NUnit in C#, a custom Authorize Attribute. In particular that a particular http status code and message have been returned in the case of not being authorized.

My attribute is super simple - looks like this:

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (IsAuthorized(actionContext))
            return;

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You are not authorized to access this resource");
    }
}
```

So to test this (and currently new in the field of testing) I have cobbled together the following code. In it, i am attaching a generic identity with a username and some role data.

```
public void Given_UserIsNotInAuthorizedRoles_When_Auhtorizing_ReturnsForbidden()
{

    // Arrange

    IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("TestName"), new[] { "TestRole" });

    HttpActionContext mockActionContext = new HttpActionContext()
    {
        ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext()
        {
            Request = new HttpRequestMessage(),
            RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext() { Principal = principal }
        },
        ActionArguments = { { "SomeArgument", "null" } }
    };

    mockActionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    mockActionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

    // Act
    AuthorizationAttribute authAttr = new AuthorizationAttribute();
    authAttr.OnAuthorization(mockActionContext);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(mockActionContext.Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

}
```

The mock controller looks like this:

```
[Authorization(Roles = "AdminRoleOnly", Users = "A user")]
internal class MockController : ApiController { }
```

When I'm debugging, i am finding that `if (IsAuthorized(actionContext))` is returning `true` - which i don't understand.

Can someone point me in the direction of why my authorize attribute is passing this identity as good?

For what it's worth, this code works in production. I'm back-filling some tests.

---

Somewhat related, are these ones

I've read through the question and answer on a similar question [ASP.NET MVC unit testing custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701433/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-custom-authorizeattribute) though neither really either work nor relate, especially given they're for MVC controllers and not Api Controllers.

I've also read and tried to implement the code in the answer on this question too [Mocking HttpActionContext.ActionArguments when testing Web.Api ActionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230081/mocking-httpactioncontext-actionarguments-when-testing-web-api-actionfilter)

---

The latter gets me somewhere near in that my authorization attribute is firing in a test and I am able to pass in the required context information.

Comment: Which beavior are you expecting? if (IsAuthorized(actionContext)) is returning true it means that the mockActionContext you provide is valid :) Any idea of what happens in the IsAuthorized function?

Comment: I expect IsAuthorized to return false. My principle has different roles from the mocked controllers AuthorizeAttribute. My principle is Authenticated, which is different though. The IsAuthorized method i'm calling is in the base of AuthorizeAttribute. MSDN says it just Indicates whether the specified control is authorized. which i understand to happen based on roles etc.

Comment: Take a look at what is happening in the source code for [IsAuthorized](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L84)

Comment: @Nkosi - thanks. Then why, if i remove the principle altogether does it not return false? It should return false on the first `if`

Comment: Hi, i would like to ask: i am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the line:
 `authAttr.OnAuthorization(mockActionContext);`
not sure what i did wrong?

Comment: @zeroflaw You probably got it sorted, but for those running in to the same issue- make sure that the response object on the context isn't null :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a `Role` to the `AuthorizationAttribute`. In your example you have a `TestRole` assign to the principal. Assign any other role but that.

```
// Act
AuthorizationAttribute authAttr = new AuthorizationAttribute() {
    Roles = "SomeOtherRole"
};
```

and the test should behave as expected when exercised.

If you review the source code for [IAuthorized](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L84) You will see logic that checks if there are roles assigned to the attribute. If there are none to compare it will default to `true`.